# What is difference between a regular model checkpoint and a saved model in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

There's a fairly clear difference between a model and a frozen model. As described [in model_files](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/extend/model_files), relevant part: *Freezing*
*...so there's the freeze_graph.py script that takes a graph definition and a set of checkpoints and freezes them together into a single file.*

- Is a "saved_model" most similar to a "frozen_model" (and not a saved
  "model_checkpoint")?
- Is this defined somewhere in docs I'm missing?
- In prior versions of tensorflow we would save and restore model
  weights, but this seems to be in context of a "model_checkpoint" not
  a "saved_model", is that still correct?

I'm asking more for the design overview here, not implementation specifics.

Answer (score 3):

Checkpoint file only contains variables for specific model and should be loaded with  either exactly same, predefined graph or with specific `assignment_map` to load only chosen variables. See https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/init_from_checkpoint

Saved model is more broad cause it contains graph that can be loaded within a session and training could be continued. Frozen graph, however, is serialized and could not be used to continue training.
You can find all the info here https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model